# R Match predefined topics to texts

Tags: r, cluster-computing, text-classification, topic-modeling

I have some topics and a lot of texts. I need to match the topics to the texts. So I was asking if there is a package in R which can do so. Here´s some sample data:

```
texts = c("I like my pet. It is a dog which has brown hair. He likes to play with other dogs.", "There are many colours like blue, red, yellow, orange or purple. My dog is brown.", "School was very boring today. My teacher also fell asleep.")
topics = c("pets", "school", "colour")
```

The desired output should be something like this:

```
result = data.frame(texts, c("pets", "colour", "school"))
```

I found some options to cluster the texts, e.g. kmeans. But then I would just get numbers which represent the clusters. 
Is it possible to match the texts to those predefined topics?

Comment: What are the rules you use to assign a particular topic to a text?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://rpubs.com/saqib/DocumentClustering), maybe you'll find ideas.

Comment: Seems you are rather asking for the right method for your problem, in this case, I would recommend to ask on [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Concerning a programmatic solution you can either search your text for predefined keywords, e.g. after creating a dtm with, e.g., `text2vec::create_dtm` (you would need a dictionary for each topic), or you can use clustering as you did with `kmeans`, or a generative algorithm for topic modelling (e.g. via `topicmodels::LDA`), or a non-negative matrix factorization approach. The three latter do not directly consider predefined topics.